# How to pass in the result of an async call to shared functions in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, supertest

### Problem

I am testing API endpoints and have some tests which are the same for every endpoint. Instead of copy and paste, I would like to share it in a reusable function. I also want a statement to be printed to the console (via `test`) for every function, so I don't want to combine the logic.

### Code

Here is the function which should be shared:

```
export function basicTests(res) {
  test("should respond with a 200 status code", () => {
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });

  test("should specify json in the content type header", () => {
    expect(res.headers["content-type"]).toEqual(expect.stringContaining("json"));
  });

  test("should return an ok property", () => {
    expect(res.body.ok).toBeDefined();
  });

  test("should return a description property", () => {
    expect(res.body.description).toBeDefined();
  });
}
```

And here is how I would call the tests in another file:

```
let res = {}
beforeAll(async () => {
  const response = await request(app)
    .get("/some/api/check")
    .send();

  res = { ...response };
});

describe("GET /some/api/route", () => {
  basicTests(res);
  // ... more tests
});
```

### What does not work

Currently when I pass in `res`, it is always an empty object. So even that `beforeAll` runs before the tests, the variable seems to be passed earlier and so gets not updated when the *Promise* resolves.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test cases are defined synchronously. That means the `res` is empty object `{}` when the `basicTests` function executes.

`beforeAll(fn, timeout)`:

> Runs a function before any of the tests in this file run. If the function returns a promise or is a generator, Jest waits for that promise to resolve before running tests.

That means the function passed in `beforeAll` will be run before the test cases functions are executed. Since the function returns a promise, jest waits for that promise.

The main difference is declaration and runtime.

One solution is to put the `beforeAll` things into `basicTests` function. E.g.

`basicTests.ts`:

```
import request from 'supertest';

export function basicTests(app, route) {
  describe('basic test suites', () => {
    let res;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      const response = await request(app).get(route);
      res = { ...response };
    });
    test('should respond with a 200 status code', () => {
      expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });

    test('should specify json in the content type header', () => {
      expect(res.headers['content-type']).toEqual(expect.stringContaining('json'));
    });

    test('should return an ok property', () => {
      expect(res.body.ok).toBeDefined();
    });

    test('should return a description property', () => {
      expect(res.body.description).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
}
```

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/some/api/check', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ ok: true, description: null, data: 'a' });
});

export { app };
```

`app.test.ts`:

```
import { basicTests } from './basicTests';
import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from './app';

describe('GET /some/api/route', () => {
  basicTests(app, '/some/api/check');
  let res;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get('/some/api/check');
    res = { ...response };
  });
  test('should return data', () => {
    expect(res.body.data).toBe('a');
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/70702998/app.test.ts (8.972 s)
  GET /some/api/route
    ✓ should return data
    basic test suites
      ✓ should respond with a 200 status code (2 ms)
      ✓ should specify json in the content type header
      ✓ should return an ok property
      ✓ should return a description property

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.042 s
```